# How to get environment variables in a service container?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

According to the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/external_parameters.html), env() parameters were introduced in version 3.2, allowing to use environment variables in service container configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
```

However, when I try using this functionality in Drupal I get an exception stating:

`The service XXX has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "env(DATABASE_HOST)"`

Looking at the stack trace I only see references to the default `ResolveParameterPlaceholdersPass` and not to `ResolveEnvPlaceholdersPass`

I'm using Drupal 8.6.5 which uses symfony/dependency-injection v3.4.20

Comment: Maybe I don't understand well, but why don't use .env file provided by Drupal ?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure if it's supported or not.

Comment: This isn't supported. Here's a link to a "Plan" issue meaning it's an idea on maybe implementing it: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2879846